# How to programatically add an IP printer present in a network to a windows machine using VC++ and Windows API's

Tags: c++, windows, networking, printing, addition

On a windows system, Is it possible to programatically Add/Edit/Delete an IP Printer present in the network to any machine  present in the same network ???

I can see on MSDN about Printer Spooler API's AddPrinter(), DeletePrinter(), SetPrinterData() and other functions to do the same.

So, say if IP of the IP Printer is 192.168.1.252 then how to Add it on a machine 192.168.1.30 present in the same network ?

The driver of the printer is not installed on 192.168.1.30 and I know only the IP and the Port the IP Printer is installed on.

I did google a lot but did not get a solution.

Comment: It is operating system specific. On my OS there is [cups](https://www.cups.org/)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch by referencing MSDN I have to assume the OS is Windows.

Comment: I agree, but the OP did not tag his question (and I think a *Windows* tag is probably missing)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch  I have mentioned about MSDN & the specific API's and hence the OS is windows xp, 7 or 8 and later

Comment: Please edit your question to improve it by tagging it as Windows

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Done with the edit. Thanks